# Rails use text_fields instead of multi select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, collections, view

I have a parent child relationship that is working with a multi select view...

```
    = f.collection_select :item_ids, Item.order("name ASC").all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, class: "form-control"}
```

Which allows the user to select several items in a multi-select and works.

However I want to limit the user to three items, and I want them to type them into an typeahead style text field.

```
= f.text_field "item_ids[]", {class: "form-control item-autocomplete", autocomplete: "off"}
= f.text_field "item_ids[]", {class: "form-control item-autocomplete", autocomplete: "off"}
= f.text_field "item_ids[]", {class: "form-control item-autocomplete", autocomplete: "off"}
```

I am having some trouble figuring out how to replace the view and still get the controller to accept the inputs as it did before items_ids[].

I would think this would be straight forward but can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I had to hack my own solution, not proud of it but since no experts answered my question and I still needed to solve the problem, I felt dirty and hacked it.

In order to solve the problem I manually created inputs that all push into an array using the name profile[item_ids][] but instead of them passing ids, they pass in strings.

Then in the controller I created a method to perform the item lookup built an array of ids and swapped out the param hash value with the new array. And in order to preserve the whitelisted params I pass it the whitelist params and return a new hash that with the item_ids with the new value like so...

```
if @profile.update(convert_item_names_to_ids(profile_params))
```

I would have never done this in a strongly typed language.